Is there a good reason I shouldn't leave my mixer on all the time?
I have a Mackie Onyx mixer.  My workflow now is turn it on along with my other equipment, open ableton, and get to work.  It would be simpler to just turn on the other devices (those that are not the mixer) and get to work, since when I turn the mixer off Ableton loses it as an audio device and I have to reconfigure it each time.  To do this I'd leave the mixer on all the time.
I have noticed it seems to draw a fair amount of power at idle (when its amplifiers are not in use, but the unit is on).  I need to check that out further since I expect it to consume relatively little power while not amplifying.
Other than power consumption is there a reason not to leave the mixer on all the time (24/7)?

Why are you turning off everything else? Same thinking would apply to the mixer.

Put a note next to the power switch, "remember to close Ableton before powering off the mixer?"

@piiperiReinstateMonica (And also to continue to power on the mixer before starting Ableton?)

I don't have a powered or USB-enabled mixer (Spirit Folio), but I am in the habit of keeping it on 24/7.  However, I do pull down all the faders when I'm finished, primarily to avoid any nasty pops or surges when my computers are turned off or rebooted.
